# Animation while changing background image (C# winrt)

Tags: windows, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am working on windows 8 music app. I am changing background of page with image of current song/album. I want to add fadeIn/dafeOut animation while I am changing image but can't figure out how I can do that.

```
    <Grid  x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource  ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="fadeOutStoryBoard">
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutRoot.Background).(ImageBrush.Opacity)"
                    From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:10"/>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="fadeInStoryBoard">
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutRoot.Background).(ImageBrush.Opacity)"
                    From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:10"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>

    In C# code: 
    ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush();
    image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
    fadeOutStoryBoard.Begin();
    MainPage.Current.LayoutRoot.Background = image;
    fadeInStoryBoard.Begin();
```

Image changes fine but I don't see animation. I tried changing TargetProperty to (LayoutRoot.Background).Opacity or (LayoutRoot.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity) but no luck. If I set TargetProperty to "Opacity" then animation works but applies to whole page and not just background.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the image as background of the page, add another Grid/Border that will hold the background. Use `Opacity` as `TargetProperty` in the animation.

The reason is that the current animation is working on the old image brush and not the new one that you created.